# Unclosed file handle when filtering file lines

Tags: groovy, filehandle

I've noticed that following code snippet in Groovy lefts unclosed file handle in JVM. I cannot remove this file until GC runs and closes resource by invoking finalizer.

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
new File("file.txt").filterLine(writer) { it.startsWith("a") }
println writer.toString()
```

**How to properly close the file when filtering its lines?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filterLine` works on a reader too, so you can do:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter()
new File("file.txt").withReader { r ->
   r.filterLine(writer) { it.startsWith("a") }
}
println writer.toString()
```

`withReader` closes the reader afterwards

Comment: PS:  [Raised an issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8373) about this resource leak

Comment: Thank you Tim, this looked like a bug in Groovy for me as well.

Comment: No probs!  Good spot :-D  Have fun!  I might send a pull request to fix it if I get time ;-)